# Dot Net Nuke 7.2 (To get RollInfo by Role name)

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am using DNN 7.2 I want to get RoleInfo Object by Roll name.
Please suggest

Following code giving me error 
RoleController.GetRoleByName(portalSettings.PortalId, Role);

Error :Error    35  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'DotNetNuke.Security.Roles.RoleController.GetRoleByName(int, string)'

Answer (score 3):

I got it.

var roleController = new RoleController();
                    RoleInfo roleInfo = roleController.GetRoleByName(portalSettings.PortalId, Role);